# Disable hyperlink opening browser from c# winforms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

We have a .Net application that embeds google maps in some of the pages.  We would like to prevent the user from opening a `WebBrowser` control when they click on a link found in Google Maps (such as in info tips on places etc...).  Is this possible?  I'm fairly new to .Net :)

Comment: You can prevent the navigation to web pages by setting the AllowNavigation property of webBrowser as false. It will be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent navigations that are based on clicking a link using these 2 ways:

1- Using `AllowNavigation` property

```
this.webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = false;
```

2- Using `Navigating` event

```
private void BrowserSample_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
    this.webBrowser1.Navigating += webBrowser1_Navigating;
}

private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    //you can use e.Url to allow or deny navigation based on your logic
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Consider these notes when using one of the ways above:

- Using `Navigating` event you can gain more control over navigation and you can prevent some navigations and allow some others.
- When using `Navigating` event, remember to add handler of this event only after you navigated to your desired url.
- Using these ways, you can only prevent navigations that are based on clicking a link, for example if you set the initial url too google, then you can perform search but you can't navigate to urls or results.

Comment: Brilliant.  thanks.  Turns out that I needed both approaches.  The 1st worked inside my popup windows and the second worked inside my main windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the navigation using [WebBrowser.AllowNavigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.allownavigation(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Seem Aghaeis answer was more complete and sorted me fully